# How to determine the average function on an interval

Tags: probability, integration, average

Let's say that I pick two random $x$ values on $[-1,1]$ and square each value to get the correspond $y$ value, thus:
$$(x_1, x_1^2), (x_2, x_2^2).$$
I then find the equation for the line connecting these two points.

Say I repeated this $1,000$ times (or $10,000$, or $100,000$, etc.). How could I determine the average equation that I would get?

Comment: It seems that $y=0$ might be the average equation

Comment: That is the truth, I believe, but how can I prove this mathematically?

Comment: You should be able to prove this without doing any calculation by the symmetry of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any randomly-chosen $x_1$ and $x_2$, the line passing through $(x_1, x_1^2)$ and $(x_2, x_2^2)$  is $$y = (x_1 + x_2) x -x_1 x_2.$$
By taking expectations, we get
$$E[y] = y=E[x_1+x_2]x-E[x_1 x_2].$$
Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are chosen independently, and  $E[x_1]=E[x_2]=0$, we have $E[x_1 x_2]=E[x_1]E[x_2]=0$.
Consequently, the equation of the line you are looking for is
$$y = 0.$$